# Decode in SQL. ЗАПРОС(SELECT), DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Здравствуйте, есть такая проблема. У меня существуют две таблицы

```
    GOODS  

   ID | NAME
    1 | book
    2 | notebook
    3 | pen
    4 | pencil    


            GOODS_OPERATION
ID | GOODS_ID | OPER_DATE | OPER_TYPE | AMOUNT
1      1        3/21/2017     1          100
2      4        5/13/2017     1          150
3      4        6/10/2017    -1          70
4      2        5/20/2017     1          200
5      2        6/10/2017    -1          150
6      3        8/11/2017     1          30
7      1        1/20/2018    -1          20
8      1        1/26/2018    -1          30
```

Нужно вывести (селект) продукт, сумму продуктов всего предыдущего года(2017), ввод продуктов в новом году, вывод продуктов в новом году и сумму продуктов в новом году. В таблице когда oper_type=1 то это ввод, -1 это вывод.

Использовала следующий код:

```
Select name as product,
       decode(sign(sysdate-oper_date), -1, sum(oper_type *amount)) as sum_2017,
       decode(sign(sysdate-oper_date), 1,sum((oper_type+1)/2*amount)) as income_18,
       decode(sign(sysdate-oper_date), 1,sum((oper_type-1)/2*amount)) as outcome_18,
       decode(sign(sysdate-oper_date), 1,sum(oper_type *amount)) as sum_2018,
from test.goods
join test.goods_operation on (goods.id = goods_operation.goods_id)
group by name.oper_date;
```

Работает неверно! Как быть? Помогите

Comment: а почему group by по дате. Если вам нужна сумма за год, может group by не нужен или например, если суммы по продуктам то group by по продукту соответственно. А что касается decode то скорее всего они должны быть внутри sum: `sum(decode(sign(sysdate-oper_date)),-1,oper_type *amount,0) as sum_2017` правда не понимаю причем тут именно 2017 и гдне проверка на год. данное условие будет делить в разные колонки суммы до сегодняшнего дня и после него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял, что понимается под "сумма в предыдущем году" - туда должна попасть сумма операций, проведенных исключительно в 2017 году, или же сумма операций, проведенных ДО 2017 года включительно? Так что в двух вариантах и предыдущий год, и текущий, неверный вариант сами уберете:

```
select g.name, 
sum(decode(extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from go.oper_date),1,go.oper_type*go.amount,0)) as sum_previous_year,--сумма только за 2017 год
sum(decode(extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from go.oper_date),0,0,go.oper_type*go.amount)) as sum_previous_year2,--сумма до 2017 года включительно
sum(decode(extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from go.oper_date),0,decode(go.oper_type,1,go.amount,0))) as income,
sum(decode(extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from go.oper_date),0,decode(go.oper_type,-1,go.amount,0))) as outcome,
sum(decode(extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from go.oper_date),0,go.oper_type*go.amount,0)) as sum_current_year,--сумма только за 2018 год
sum(go.oper_type*go.amount) as sum_current_year2--сумма до 2018 года включительно
from goods g join
goods_operation go on g.id = go.goods_id
GROUP BY g.name
```

Плюс можно результаты суммирования в coalesce обернуть, потому что по некоторым позициям операции приход/расход не проводились в 2018 году.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!)

Comment: Да не за что :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with a as (
select
b.oper_date datadata, 
a.name product,
sum(case when b.oper_type > 0 then oper_type else 0 end) income,
sum(case when b.oper_type < 0 then oper_type else 0 end) outcome,
sum(b.oper_type) summa,
(amount - summa) ostalos
from goods a join goods_operation b on a.id = b.goods_id
group by product, datadata)
select * from a
where oper_date between to_date('1/01/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date ('12/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
union all
select * from a 
where oper_date between to_date('1/01/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') and trunc(sysdate)
```

Опробуйте, пожалуйста и напишите результат

Декод тут по сути не нужен. Зачем? Легче создать ссылочную таблицу и тянуть данные оттуда.

---

Решениче через decode

```
with a as (
select
b.oper_date datadata, 
a.name product,
sum(decode(b.oper_type, 1, b.oper_type)) income,
sum(decode(b.oper_type, -1, b.oper_type)) outcome,
sum(b.oper_type) summa,
(amount - summa) ostalos
from goods a join goods_operation b on a.id = b.goods_id
group by product, datadata)
select * from a
where oper_date between to_date('1/01/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date ('12/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
union all
select * from a 
where oper_date between to_date('1/01/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') and  
trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: и я хотела сделать через case when, но требуют чтоб был без него.. и с decode.

Comment: @YagutHajizadeh что именно нужно декодом сделать и какие комментарии к подсчету?

Comment: требуется с его помощью вывести данные за определенную дату @Foxey

Comment: Попробуйте, я написал для decode. Но, если значение вывода будет > 1 или < -1, то это решение не подходит